# leaflet time-slider play button

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere, but is there a good way to add a 'play' button to a leaflet range-slider to automatically scroll through time?  I have a range-slider that indexes the year:

```
    $('#reverse').html('<img src="/js/Residents_Map_Nov14/img/left2.png"">');
    $('#forward').html('<img src="/js/Residents_Map_Nov14/img/right2.png">');
    $('.skip').click(function () {

        var index = $('.range-slider').val();
        //if forward clicked, increasing increments by 1
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'forward') {
            index++;
            index = index > 2016 ? 1970 : index;
            map.legend.setContent(index);
        }
     }
```

So, my question is, how would one add a 'play' button that would automatically play through each year?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to change the content of the map as the time goes by. Doing that by hand is might be a lot of work (depending on how many things you have to change).

My advice would be to use a Leaflet plugin for the time dimension, like [this one](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension). This one allows you to change layers using WMS or GEOJSON.

You have other plugins, for example if you only want to change markers.
I suggest you check out [these plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#time--elevation)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks- I looked at this, I wonder if it'd work with an existing range-slider?  I want to keep everything I have but just add a play button..

Comment: Well, I pointed you in the direction of these plugins because I assumed you wanted to change the map when changing the year, and I thought that could be a lot of work. I think you can't adapt these plugins to an existing range-slider, unless you change the plugins source code (I don't recommend it).
But if you don't mind altering the map yourself, then this is a Javascript/jQuery question. In here https://jsfiddle.net/qs6dL200, you can see a range slider incrementing each 0.5 s (I've left some comments where you can change the map).

Comment: H. Figueiredo - thanks so much, this worked.  However, it seems to get stuck on "play" when I double click the "start" button.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to check for double inputs. [This](https://jsfiddle.net/w3cwhh1w/) should do the trick, it should have normal behavior when you click a second time (It basically ignores the second 'click').